# R: nice way to create 1 to K etiquettes for categorical data

Tags: r

I would like to convert any kind of categorical data so that every unique category would have a label numbered from 1 to K, with K being the number of unique labels in the set. As an output I want a numeric variable.

I use following 'hack' for this purpose:

```
x <- sample(letters, 100, replace=T)
y <- sample(10, 100, replace=T)

as.numeric(as.factor(as.character(x)))
as.numeric(as.factor(as.character(y)))
```

However it doesn't seem to be an efficient way to do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: What makes `sample` and/or `factor` inefficient?

Comment: You can try `match(x,unique(x))` for instance, but `factor`s are made for this very purpose.

Comment: A quick benchmark indicates minor speed improvement if you use `as.integer` instead of `as.numeric`

Comment: I don't think it's inefficient, maybe you just mean that the syntax is not very pleasing? Try `factor(x, labels = "")` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @konvas and @beginneR I have chosen this solution:

```
as.integer(factor(x, labels=""))
```